# Edit JPA-Mapping in IntelliJ Idea

Tags: java, entity-framework, jpa, intellij-idea

I'm having a JPA-Project in IntelliJ Idea and there are some entities my colleague mapped some time ago. Now the DB team added a bunch of tables I'm trying to add as entities to the Java-Project. But when I'm trying to map a new entity to a existing entity IntelliJ Idea doesn't know the entity. So I'm wondering, if the only way is to re-import the table?

[image: BankEntity exists in the JavaProject, but the mapper doesn't recognize it.]

BankEntity exists in the JavaProject, but the mapper doesn't recognize it.

Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to answer my own question: When generating the entities, Intelli recognizes that there is an existing entity and only add the new attributes to that class. It's somehow confusing, that you have to select the entity like a new entity...but it work's.

Answer (score 0):

If it is an entity that is newly added to the Intellij project, it is unaware of the related table in the database.

You have to *Generate Persistence Mapping -> By Database Schema* and choose/define the the datasource and then import the table. If the definition of an already mapped entity have been changed(e.g. new column added), then a refresh might help.

Comment: I did so. There is a new table which has a 1:n relation with an existing table. I'm trying to add the relation between the new and the existing table into a new and an existing entity. But the IntelliJ Dialog doesn't recognize the existing entity.

Comment: so the new table maps to the existing class? So until now, that existing class was not marked as a JPA entity?

Comment: The existing class (BankEntity) is marked as a entity. As I understand your answers, this should work generally?